# Incompatible types error Java

Tags: java, incompatibletypeerror

So, I have this line of code

```
ScreenCapture.main(String[].class);
```

in file "1" and it is linking to this file "2"

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

class ScreenCapture
{
   public static void main (String args[]) throws
        AWTException, IOException
   {
      System.out.print(".");
      BufferedImage screencapture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(
            new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()) );
      Expo.delay(2000);
      System.out.print(".");
      File file = new File("Agreement.jpg");
      ImageIO.write(screencapture, "jpg", file);
      Expo.delay(4000);
      System.out.print(".");
   }
}
```

and this is the error I get in file 1

```
WarandPeace.java:21: error: incompatible types: Class<String[]> cannot be
converted to String[]
```

My end goal is to take a screenshot of the screen when the user completes a specific action in file 1. I have the screenshot file working (file 2), but no matter what I do, that error keeps being annoying (file 1). Any solutions?

Comment: Who about `ScreenCapture.main(new String[0]);` instead...

Answer (score 4):

Your error is self-explanatory. A String array class is not the same as a String array itself. But more importantly, that code should not be in a static main method if you want other code to use it since the main method should be used for starting a program, not for utility methods. Learn proper OOPS concepts, create classes and call non-static methods of proper objects. If this were my code, I'd create a method to capture the screen and have it return a BufferedImage. Then other code can decide what to do with the BufferedImage.

Comment: I'd really like a close option for these types of questions, but I can only come up with statements that are derogative...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: We'd need a "cart-before-the-horse" close reason, something like closed for trying to tackle advanced concepts before learning basic concepts.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels like the old "lacks a minimal understanding of the problem"? (that was, of course, derogatory)

Comment: "Question would be better answer by read suitable tutorials" :P

Answer (score 1):

The method in file 2 has this signature:

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws
        AWTException, IOException
```

You need to match it. You can do e.g. this:

```
ScreenCapture.main(new String[] {"param1", "param2"});
```

or, since you are not using the arguments at all, you can just:

```
ScreenCapture.main(new String[] {});
```

I agree with [the other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28422791/438544) answer though...

Answer (score 0):

Modify "file 1".

```
ScreenCapture.main(String[].class);
```

should be

```
String[] args = { "one" }; // <- for one.
```

or

```
String[] args = new String[0]; // <- for none.
```

and then

```
ScreenCapture.main(args);
```

`main()` takes an array of `String`(s) (not the `Class<String[]>` which is the type of a `String[]`).

Finally, on one line -

```
ScreenCapture.main(new String[] {"one", "two"});
```